# C# Split string for dictionary use

Tags: c#, .net, string, dictionary, split

My old project opened a file and read the parameters with the following code.

But for my new project I need this done from a string (not from a file), but as it turns out that's a lot harder for me.

I now need to find a solution, where I can read parameters from a string with data["parameter"]. My goal is, that I dont need to use a file.

Thank you for your help

-

***file.txt***

```
username = xela
name = Alex
Doab = 178199
zip = 88911
```

***C# Code:***

```
var data = File
    .ReadAllLines(Path.GetTempPath() + "file.txt")
    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
    .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);

//Get data
Textbox.Text = data["name"];
Textbox1.Text = data["zip"];
```

***Output***

```
Textbox Output would be "Alex"
Textbox1 Output would be "88911"
```

***Solution***

```
var data = @"username = xela
      name = Alex
      Doab = 178199
      zip = 88911"
        .Split('\n').ToArray()
        .ToDictionary(
          x => x.Split('=')[0].Trim(), 
          x => x.Split('=')[1].Trim(' ', '\r'))
```

;

Comment: Please show an example string.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Replace `File.ReadAllLines(...)` with the string split by new line (e.g. `yourString.Split('\n')` of course you'd need to check if there are `\r`, too).

Comment: @RenéVogt I am sorry, but I can't follow you. Could you please help me a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple one-liner will do it:

```
File.ReadLines(Path.GetTempPath() + "file.txt")
  .ToDictionary(
    x => x.Split('=')[0].Trim(), 
    x => x.Split('=')[1].Trim());
```

Or if the source is a string:

```
var data = @"username = xela
      name = Alex
      Doab = 178199
      zip = 88911"
        .Split('\n')
        .ToDictionary(
          x => x.Split('=')[0].Trim(), 
          x => x.Split('=')[1].Trim(' ', '\r'))
```

;

Comment: But the problem is, that I don't want to use a file for the solution. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Why? you have to read the content of a file right?

Comment: No I want it done from a string. One of my former projects used to do it from an extra created file. This is for safety-reasons.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to split up a simple string

Comment: Are there line breaks? I need to know the delimiter.

Comment: Yes there are linebreaks, but it worked. Thank you.